# Moving pacman from root to /home partition

Tags: arch-linux, partition, pacman

Back before I knew what I was doing, I installed my Arch system with a 10 GB root and an 85 GB /home partition. Now my 10 GB root (where my pacman installs to) is full and I'm unable to get gparted running on my computer (it's a mac) to resize because my CD-ROM drive isn't working.

Is there an easy way to set my system up so that pacman installs and runs from my home partition where there is plenty of room?

Comment: Only to mention: GParted also run form USB.

Comment: Not on a Mac. I've tried everything to create a bootable gparted USB. I can't get it to load.

Comment: Ah, ok. Too bad.

Comment: Which filesystem? Maybe you can clean package cache, or move some big directory to another partition.

Comment: Oops. I actually forgot I asked that. Sorry.

Comment: So how did you install ArchLinux?

Comment: My cd drive was working when I installed Arch. Booted from CD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving pacman is not the right approach.

You do, however, have a couple of options. All of them assume that you already have a full and tested backup of your data.

First, make sure that you have cleared all available space in pacman's cache with `pacman -Sc`: pass the second `c` for everything. There is a pacman tool for more fine-grained control fo this, see `paccache --help` for details.

If that still does not provide enough room, then you can resize your partitions with `fdisk` which is part of `util-linux` and is installed in the [base group](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/base/). There are a number of guides online for doing this.

The optimal solution, though, would be to grasp the nettle and do a full reinstall using [LVM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lvm) so that you have the flexibility to work around this issue (as well as other benefits like snapshotting) in the future. You could also fully encrypt your drive(s) while you are at it with [LVM on LUKS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_Entire_System#LVM_on_LUKS).